# Как использовать гем только в локальной версии приложения?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler

Есть Rails-проект. Хочу использовать гем для форматирования вывода данных в консоли, но не хочу, чтобы он попал в репозиотории. Как такое провернуть не переделывая каждый раз перед коммитом файлы?

Comment: А откуда такое нежелание добавлять его в Gemfile?

Comment: Проект чужой, разработчики не хотят видеть в нем "левые" гемы. К тому же, он немного изменяет поведение приложения.
Вроде обчная ситуация, но почему-то решения не могу найти.

Comment: А что за гем? Так будет проще помочь, я думаю.

Answer (score 1):

В терминале выполните `gem install gemname`.

Если используете rvm, то нужный вам гем будет установлен в текущий гемсет. Если нужно установить его для всех гемсетов текущей версии руби - `rvm @global do gem install gemname`.

С rbenv никогда не работала, поэтому про его особенности не в курсе.

Comment: rvm использую. Вроде так пробовал, без bundle install гем не работал. И как быть с настройками, которые изменят файлы приложения, например, нужно прописывать reuqire.

Comment: Ещё один вариант - не коммитить строки с этими изменениями, у меня так в одном проекте уже год в Gemfile&Gemfile.lock висит letter_opener. Вы через терминал коммиты делаете или через GUI какой-нибудь?

Comment: Через терминал, гем awesome_print. Так-то меня интересует общий подход, как действовать в такой ситуации.

Comment: @MrAak, awesome_print у меня тоже не захотел работать без указания в Gemfile. Я это решила pry-rails, она даёт красивый вывод в консоли и чудесные возможности дебаггинга через `binding.pry`. Собственно, добавляешь её в гемфайл и не коммитишь, но через терминал это неудобно. Я пользую GitHub Desktop, если у вас не Мак, то рекомендую GitKraken

Comment: Ну а общий подход - в моём ответе :)